# Multiple Monitors on Poweredge r710?

Tags: dell-poweredge

My desktop pc is dead, i have poweredge r710 and i 've decided to use it as my workstation. I installed windows 7, but there is only 1 port for monitor on the back..I want to run dual monitors as my old pc.

can you one recommend what i need to buy to be able to run multiple monitors ?

Thanks.

Comment: I think this question should be moved to superuser.

Answer (score 2):

An r710 is a bit expensive (and loud) to be using as a desktop. You need to buy a new video card though. Something that is PCI Express and supports dual monitors.

My opinion is that you should sell the r710 if you're not going to use it as a server. Then you can buy yourself a proper workstation.

Answer (score 1):

You will need: A new video card and earplugs to use the R710 as a workstation. Don't forget the earplugs. It will not be happy to be sitting on a desk without a nice free airflow and it will signal its displeasure by making its fans scream at incredibly high volume.

Answer (score -2):

"A new video card and earplugs to use the R710 as a workstation. Don't forget the earplugs. "

Yes, you will need a video card.... but the earplugs, not so much.  I've been running R710's for quite a while now, and they aren't nearly noisy after boot-up as some folks would lead you to believe.  Yes you can hear the fans... but no, they aren't a problem.

The only thing I can figure, is that they are so super-sensitive that they can't handle even the slightest fan noise.  I bet they  also get annoyed at birds chirping in the yard, distant trains going by, or the sound of their mothers yelling at them while they are down in their basement hide-aways.

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  This is really a critique of another answer rather than a solution to the question.  With a little more rep, you will be able to post comments to critique a post or request clarification.